# Transforming variables of dataframes stored in a list

Tags: r, transform, lapply

I have a list of dataframes, all with the same structure, which I created using the following code:

```
myfiles <- list.files(patter='.csv')
mydata <- lapply(myfiles, read.csv)
names(mydata) <- gsub("\\.csv", "", myfiles)
```

I have to run a series of calculations on each dataframe in the list. But first I have to transform the data type of certain variables. I've searched high and low for an answer but keep coming up short. The closes I've gotten is:

```
lapply(mydata, function(i) {
transform(mydata, PIN=as.character(PIN), Class=as.character(Class), TaxStatus=as.character(TaxStatus), TaxcCode=as.character(TaxCode), TaxRate(as.doublt(TaxRate) *.001), Amt1=(as.double(Amt1) *.01), Amt2=(as.double(Amt2) * .01))
})
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

> Error in data.frame(PropTax1993 = list(PIN = c(1011000020000, 1011000030000,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1443916, 1449711, 1459247, 1469691, 1480347, 1491574, 1504263, 1516502, 1530584

I assume this is because the dataframes in my list have varying lengths. I've also tried:

```
lapply(1:length(mydata), function(i) {
transform(mydata, PIN=as.character(PIN), Class=as.character(Class), TaxStatus=as.character(TaxStatus), TaxcCode=as.character(TaxCode), TaxRate(as.doublt(TaxRate) *.001), Amt1=(as.double(Amt1) *.01), Amt2=(as.double(Amt2) * .01))
})
```

... but that doesn't work either. I'm relatively new to R (and programming in general). Any assistances would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `transform(i, PIN=as.character(..` not "mydata". And also an equals sign and to fix the typo  like `TaxRate=(as.double(TaxRate)*.001)`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, and this is probably quite possible with one of the apply functions (which would be better for a more optimized solution), but here's a for loop solution I just worked out that should do the trick:

```
# Creating sample data frames (all the same content).
myDF <- data.frame(a = seq(1, 50), b = seq(1, 100, 2) , c = seq(1, 200, 4))
myDF2 <- myDF
myDF3 <- myDF

# Creating a sample list of those data frames.
myList <- list(myDF, myDF2, myDF3)

# The data is in integer form.
print(class(myList[[1]]$a))

# Looping through each data frame in the list and changing each the same way.
for(item in 1:length(myList)) {

  myList[[item]]$a <- as.character(myList[[item]]$a) # Coercing the data type of each column here.
  myList[[item]]$b <- as.character(myList[[item]]$b)
  myList[[item]]$c <- as.character(myList[[item]]$c)

}

# The data is now in character form.
print(class(myList[[1]]$a))
```

Just change the column names (a, b and c) in the for loop and the function you are using to coerce the columns.

Also noting that the double bracket, `[[1]]`, notation is special to pulling data out of a list. For vectors or arrays, it's just a single bracket.